# Which Material Design framework can I use for supporting Nested Tabs in my website?

Tags: jquery, tabs, nested, material-design, material-design-lite

I am building a web page which is going to have Nested Tabs. And I want it to have Material Design. I had been using [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/started/) but based on my experience, as well as [this](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1173), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875975/nested-tabs-in-material-design-lite-nested-tabs-dont-completely-respond-to-cl) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699871/using-tabs-within-tab-isnt-working-material-design-lite) link, I don't think that Material Design Lite supports or is going to support Nested tabs.

So [which material design framework](http://noeticforce.com/best-material-design-web-frameworks) should I use to support Nested Tabs in my web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/). Although it is still in beta, Materialize has a good set of components and it is updated quite often. Here is an example of simple nested [tabs](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html).

```js
$(() => {
  $('ul.tabs').tabs();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 1em;
  background: skyblue;
}

div[id] {
  padding-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs z-depth-1">
      <li class="tab"><a href="#first-tab">First tab</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#second-tab">Second tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="first-tab">First tab</div>
    <div id="second-tab">
      <ul class="tabs z-depth-1">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#second-child-first">First child tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#second-child-second">Second child tab</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="second-child-first">Second child first</div>
      <div id="second-child-second">Second child second</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```